# nodejs/JS: Objects not being updated in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, for-loop

**Firstly, I am a complete noob to Javascript and Node.js.**

I tried to write a simple program that creates an array of planes that all have the same values except in index, which should take on the value of each index in the for loop from 0 - 2.

**Here is my code**

```
var plane = {
    index: -1,
    name: "A380",
    seats: {
        first: 40,
        buisness: 90,
        economy: 300
    },
    wheels: 8,
}

var planeArray = []

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    plane.index = i
    planeArray.push(plane)
  }

  console.log(planeArray)
```

But when I print the output, the indices of all the planes are 2. **Here is my output.**

```
[
  {
    index: 2,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  }
]
```

**Here is my expected output.**

```
[
  {
    index: 0,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    name: 'A380',
    seats: { first: 40, buisness: 90, economy: 300 },
    wheels: 8
  }
]
```

I don't understand why.
Could someone help me out. Also, any additional explanations/resources helpful for learning node.js would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are pushing the same object into the array multiple times.  Not multiple distinct objects.

Comment: This is called object mutation in JS. It's better you read this before moving on. https://www.zeptobook.com/object-mutation-in-javascript/

Comment: Alternatively, make it `const plane = (index) => ({ index, name: "A380",` _… etc. …_ `});` instead, and in your `for` loop just use only `planeArray.push(plane(i));`. Even better would be `const planeArray = Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, index) => plane(index));` instead of the whole `for` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is that the object being added in the array goes as a reference and not as the value of the object
you can either try either of the below two solutions.
This way you pass the object value instead of its reference.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    plane.index = i
    planeArray.push({...plane})
  }
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    plane.index = i
    planeArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(plane)))
  }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify |> JSON.parse` isn’t really elegant and doesn’t work for all kinds of objects and data types; `{ ...plane }` only copies the top layer of properties — the nested `seats` object will still have the same reference.

Answer (score -1):

You are always changing the same object with  `plane.index = i`. If you want to have three different entries in your array you need three different objects.

Comment: It's better you provide a detailed explanation with a sample solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will do in the future.